# TinyMce is not working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, tinymce

I have TinyMce to compose emails in my asp.net page, it is working fine but in Google Chrome no tools (font size, font name, text color etc for example) are working. They work fine in all other broswers. Kindly guide and help me.

Thanks

Comment: do you get any js-errors? have a look at the chrome error console. can you show your full tinymce configuration?

Comment: @Thariama, no error just I have found AtD Sepll check disturbed working of other tools in Chrome. Any suggestion plz ?

Comment: don't use AtD Spell check :)  there are alternative spellcheckers working with tinymce

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link to a HOWTO.](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3aspellchecker) It describes well how the tinymce spellchecker plugin can be configured to use a variety of spellcheckers (located on a server) and what needs to be done to make it work.